# Is there any way to output network values at prediction in Keras

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, keras

I am using Keras for some deep learning stuff. 
I have a question regarding the network state at the prediction step.

Is there any way to spot the neurons values when predicting some random input ?
(see the final neurons state for a given input).

Comment: By state you mean output?

Comment: yeah, the output at each layer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

You could create a new temporary model, which has as its output the hidden layer of the (original) network from which you want to retrieve the activation values.

As an example if you have a neural network A with 3 layers (1 input, 1 hidden and 1 output) and want to retrieve the activation values of the hidden layer, you need to create a new model, say B, which has 2 layers (1 input and 1 output). The input layer of model B, will be the same as the input layer of model A. While the output layer of model B will be like the hidden layer of model A.

An example code could be:

```
rom keras.models import Model

model = ...  # create the original model

layer_name = 'my_layer'
intermediate_layer_model = Model(inputs=model.input,
                             outputs=model.get_layer(layer_name).output)
intermediate_output = intermediate_layer_model.predict(data)
```

For more details please have a look at the Keras FAQ https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-obtain-the-output-of-an-intermediate-layer.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18628180)

Comment: @SundararajGovindasamy May you please explain me, why my response doesn't reply the question? As far as I know (and from the information in the question) in the link there is the needed information and code to solve the problem. I could have copied the code here, but I don't see any reason for it.

Comment: Please read - Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”? - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Comment: @SundararajGovindasamy Thanks for your advice, I edited the answer, which now contains more details and explanation. Hope it is ok now.